# Angular Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, webpack, ng2-dragula

I've been trying to use dragula in my Angular 2 app, but I can't make it work.

Here is what I put in my app.module.ts

```
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...
        DragulaModule
    ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    providers: [
        DragulaService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In the component in which I use the Dragula, I imported it that way:

```
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {}
```

And here is the simple thing I tried to build in the view, which doesn't work:

```
<ul [dragula]="'one'" [dragulaModel]="items">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I tried importing them from 'ng2-dragula', 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula' and some others from solutions I found online, but no luck so far. When I try to console.log DragulaModule and DragulaService to see if they were found, DragularService returns a function with content, while DragulaModule returns an empty function.

Here is the error I get in the console:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("span> </div> </header> <div class="alert-container"> <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error> </div> <ul [ERROR ->][dragula]="'one'" [dragulaModel]="items"> <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li> </ul> <div cla"): MatrixDetailComponent@0:943
Can't bind to 'dragulaModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("der> <div class="alert-container"> <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error> </div> <ul [dragula]="'one'" [ERROR ->][dragulaModel]="items"> <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li> </ul> <div class="container-flui"): MatrixDetailComponent@0:961
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dragula' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("span> </div> </header> <div class="alert-container"> <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error> </div> <ul [ERROR ->][dragula]="'one'" [dragulaModel]="items"> <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li> </ul> <div cla"): MatrixDetailComponent@0:943
Can't bind to 'dragulaModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ul'. ("der> <div class="alert-container"> <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error> </div> <ul [dragula]="'one'" [ERROR ->][dragulaModel]="items"> <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li> </ul> <div class="container-flui"): MatrixDetailComponent@0:961
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `DragulaService` in the providers section? Try removing it and see if things work.

Comment: @Meir I tried removing it, I get the same error.

Comment: Is the component you are trying to use it in a part of the same module as the one you are importing dragula into?

Comment: Any luck with this yet?  I am seeing the same error.

Comment: @EricGrover try `DragulaModule.forRoot()` in your app.module

Answer (score 0):

```
import {DragulaModule} from "ng2-dragula";

@NgModule({
imports: [DragulaModule],
declarations: []
});
```

this fix will work...